# java.lang.ClassCastException Using Cipher class in java stored function Oracle Databse

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, java-6

I am trying to encrypt and encode a string using javax.crypto.cipher and org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 respectively in a java stored function in an Oracle 12c R1 database.

The following code works when run from a main method in Eclipse

```
    String key = "Bar12345Bar12345";
    Base64 base = new Base64();
    Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    String encryptedEncoded = new String(base.encode(encrypted));
    return encryptedEncoded;
```

When run inside of the Oracle JVM I get a java.lang.ClassCastException
on the following line

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

The exception raised is the following

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException at 
      javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:226) at 
        JavaCrypto.encrypt(JavaCrypto.java:17)
```

As far as I can tell the Cipher.getInstance() method does return a Cipher so I shouldn't be getting a casting error.

Comment: Full exception listing, please?

Comment: I added the stacktrace.